# libCEC not working on LG TV (LD330)

Tags: power, hdmi, display, remote

I've just installed libcec on my Raspberry Pi B+ with (raspbian on it), following the instructions from here (https://nyxi.eu/blog/2013/04/15/raspbian-libcec/).

I want to be able to turn on/off the tv via the `echo "on 0" | cec-client -s` and `echo "standby 0" | cec-client -s` commands.
But they don't work.

--

Here's what errors/logs I get on `echo "standby 0" | cec-client -s` :

```
DEBUG:   [             123] unregistering all CEC clients
DEBUG:   [             127] Broadcast (F): osd name set to 'Broadcast'
DEBUG:   [             131] InitHostCEC - vchiq_initialise succeeded
DEBUG:   [             134] InitHostCEC - vchi_initialise succeeded
DEBUG:   [             137] InitHostCEC - vchi_connect succeeded
DEBUG:   [             141] logical address changed to Free use (e)
DEBUG:   [             145] Open - vc_cec initialised
NOTICE:  [             148] connection opened
DEBUG:   [             152] << Broadcast (F) -> TV (0): POLL
DEBUG:   [             155] initiator 'Broadcast' is not supported by the CEC adapter. using 'Free use' instead
DEBUG:   [             158] processor thread started
TRAFFIC: [             162] << e0
DEBUG:   [             226] initiator 'Broadcast' is not supported by the CEC adapter. using 'Free use' instead
TRAFFIC: [             229] << e0
DEBUG:   [             322] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [             325] TV (0): device status changed into 'not present'
NOTICE:  [             329] registering new CEC client - v2.2.0
DEBUG:   [             332] detecting logical address for type 'recording device'
DEBUG:   [             335] trying logical address 'Recorder 1'
DEBUG:   [             339] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Recorder 1 (1): POLL
TRAFFIC: [             342] << 11
TRAFFIC: [             436] << 11
DEBUG:   [             529] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [             532] using logical address 'Recorder 1'
DEBUG:   [             536] Recorder 1 (1): device status changed into 'handled by libCEC'
DEBUG:   [             540] Recorder 1 (1): power status changed from 'unknown' to 'on'
DEBUG:   [             544] Recorder 1 (1): vendor = Pulse Eight (001582)
DEBUG:   [             548] Recorder 1 (1): CEC version 1.4
DEBUG:   [             551] AllocateLogicalAddresses - device '0', type 'recording device', LA '1'
DEBUG:   [             556] logical address changed to Recorder 1 (1)
DEBUG:   [             560] Recorder 1 (1): osd name set to 'CECTester'
DEBUG:   [             564] Recorder 1 (1): menu language set to 'eng'
DEBUG:   [             568] GetPhysicalAddress - physical address = 2000
DEBUG:   [             573] AutodetectPhysicalAddress - autodetected physical address '2000'
DEBUG:   [             577] Recorder 1 (1): physical address changed from ffff to 2000
DEBUG:   [             581] << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): physical adddress 2000
TRAFFIC: [             586] << 1f:84:20:00:01
NOTICE:  [             741] CEC client registered: libCEC version = 2.2.0, client version = 2.2.0, firmware version = 1, logical address(es) = Recorder 1 (1) , physical address: 2.0.0.0, host: armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, features: 'P8 USB' 'P8 USB detect' 'RPi' 'EXYNOS', git revision: 9f000e4, compiled on: Thu Feb  5 19:25:20 UTC 2015 by root@raspberrypi on Linux 3.12.28+ (armv6l)
DEBUG:   [             753] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'CECTester'
DEBUG:   [             758] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): POLL
TRAFFIC: [             763] << 10
TRAFFIC: [             858] << 10
DEBUG:   [             953] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [             957] not sending command 'set osd name': destination device 'TV' marked as not present
DEBUG:   [             962] << requesting power status of 'TV' (0)
DEBUG:   [             967] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): POLL
TRAFFIC: [             971] << 10
TRAFFIC: [            1066] << 10
DEBUG:   [            1161] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            1165] not sending command 'give device power status': destination device 'TV' marked as not present
DEBUG:   [            1171] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            1176] << 10
TRAFFIC: [            1271] << 10
DEBUG:   [            1366] >> POLL not sent
NOTICE:  [            1370] << putting 'TV' (0) in standby mode
DEBUG:   [            1374] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            1379] << 10
TRAFFIC: [            1474] << 10
DEBUG:   [            1569] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            1573] not sending command 'standby': destination device 'TV' marked as not present
DEBUG:   [            1578] unregistering all CEC clients
NOTICE:  [            1582] unregistering client: libCEC version = 2.2.0, client version = 2.2.0, firmware version = 1, logical address(es) = Recorder 1 (1) , physical address: 2.0.0.0, host: armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, features: 'P8 USB' 'P8 USB detect' 'RPi' 'EXYNOS', git revision: 9f000e4, compiled on: Thu Feb  5 19:25:20 UTC 2015 by root@raspberrypi on Linux 3.12.28+ (armv6l)
DEBUG:   [            1596] Recorder 1 (1): power status changed from 'on' to 'unknown'
DEBUG:   [            1601] Recorder 1 (1): vendor = Unknown (000000)
DEBUG:   [            1606] Recorder 1 (1): CEC version unknown
DEBUG:   [            1611] Recorder 1 (1): osd name set to 'Recorder 1'
DEBUG:   [            1615] Recorder 1 (1): device status changed into 'unknown'
DEBUG:   [            1620] unregistering all CEC clients
DEBUG:   [            2167] UnregisterLogicalAddress - releasing previous logical address
DEBUG:   [            2172] logical address changed to Broadcast (f)
```

--

Also, the following is what I get on `echo "scan" | cec-client -s` :

```
DEBUG:   [             130] unregistering all CEC clients
DEBUG:   [             136] Broadcast (F): osd name set to 'Broadcast'
DEBUG:   [             141] InitHostCEC - vchiq_initialise succeeded
DEBUG:   [             145] InitHostCEC - vchi_initialise succeeded
DEBUG:   [             150] InitHostCEC - vchi_connect succeeded
DEBUG:   [             155] logical address changed to Free use (e)
DEBUG:   [             159] Open - vc_cec initialised
NOTICE:  [             164] connection opened
DEBUG:   [             169] << Broadcast (F) -> TV (0): POLL
DEBUG:   [             174] initiator 'Broadcast' is not supported by the CEC adapter. using 'Free use' instead
TRAFFIC: [             178] << e0
DEBUG:   [             179] processor thread started
DEBUG:   [             248] initiator 'Broadcast' is not supported by the CEC adapter. using 'Free use' instead
TRAFFIC: [             253] << e0
DEBUG:   [             348] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [             352] TV (0): device status changed into 'not present'
NOTICE:  [             357] registering new CEC client - v2.2.0
DEBUG:   [             362] detecting logical address for type 'recording device'
DEBUG:   [             366] trying logical address 'Recorder 1'
DEBUG:   [             371] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Recorder 1 (1): POLL
TRAFFIC: [             376] << 11
TRAFFIC: [             471] << 11
DEBUG:   [             566] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [             570] using logical address 'Recorder 1'
DEBUG:   [             575] Recorder 1 (1): device status changed into 'handled by libCEC'
DEBUG:   [             579] Recorder 1 (1): power status changed from 'unknown' to 'on'
DEBUG:   [             583] Recorder 1 (1): vendor = Pulse Eight (001582)
DEBUG:   [             587] Recorder 1 (1): CEC version 1.4
DEBUG:   [             591] AllocateLogicalAddresses - device '0', type 'recording device', LA '1'
DEBUG:   [             596] logical address changed to Recorder 1 (1)
DEBUG:   [             601] Recorder 1 (1): osd name set to 'CECTester'
DEBUG:   [             605] Recorder 1 (1): menu language set to 'eng'
DEBUG:   [             609] GetPhysicalAddress - physical address = 2000
DEBUG:   [             614] AutodetectPhysicalAddress - autodetected physical address '2000'
DEBUG:   [             618] Recorder 1 (1): physical address changed from ffff to 2000
DEBUG:   [             622] << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): physical adddress 2000
TRAFFIC: [             626] << 1f:84:20:00:01
NOTICE:  [             781] CEC client registered: libCEC version = 2.2.0, client version = 2.2.0, firmware version = 1, logical address(es) = Recorder 1 (1) , physical address: 2.0.0.0, host: armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, features: 'P8 USB' 'P8 USB detect' 'RPi' 'EXYNOS', git revision: 9f000e4, compiled on: Thu Feb  5 19:25:20 UTC 2015 by root@raspberrypi on Linux 3.12.28+ (armv6l)
DEBUG:   [             794] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'CECTester'
DEBUG:   [             799] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): POLL
TRAFFIC: [             804] << 10
TRAFFIC: [             899] << 10
DEBUG:   [             994] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [             999] not sending command 'set osd name': destination device 'TV' marked as not present
DEBUG:   [            1004] << requesting power status of 'TV' (0)
DEBUG:   [            1008] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            1013] << 10
TRAFFIC: [            1108] << 10
DEBUG:   [            1202] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            1207] not sending command 'give device power status': destination device 'TV' marked as not present
DEBUG:   [            1216] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            1221] << 10
TRAFFIC: [            1316] << 10
DEBUG:   [            1411] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            1416] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Recorder 2 (2): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            1420] << 12
TRAFFIC: [            1515] << 12
DEBUG:   [            1610] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            1615] Recorder 2 (2): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            1619] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Tuner 1 (3): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            1624] << 13
TRAFFIC: [            1719] << 13
DEBUG:   [            1814] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            1818] Tuner 1 (3): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            1823] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Playback 1 (4): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            1827] << 14
TRAFFIC: [            1922] << 14
DEBUG:   [            2017] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            2021] Playback 1 (4): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            2026] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Audio (5): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            2030] << 15
TRAFFIC: [            2125] << 15
DEBUG:   [            2219] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            2223] Audio (5): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            2226] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Tuner 2 (6): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            2230] << 16
TRAFFIC: [            2325] << 16
DEBUG:   [            2419] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            2423] Tuner 2 (6): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            2426] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Tuner 3 (7): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            2430] << 17
TRAFFIC: [            2524] << 17
DEBUG:   [            2618] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            2622] Tuner 3 (7): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            2626] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Playback 2 (8): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            2630] << 18
TRAFFIC: [            2723] << 18
DEBUG:   [            2817] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            2821] Playback 2 (8): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            2824] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Recorder 3 (9): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            2828] << 19
TRAFFIC: [            2922] << 19
DEBUG:   [            3016] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            3019] Recorder 3 (9): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            3023] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Tuner 4 (A): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            3026] << 1a
TRAFFIC: [            3120] << 1a
DEBUG:   [            3214] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            3217] Tuner 4 (A): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            3221] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Playback 3 (B): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            3225] << 1b
TRAFFIC: [            3319] << 1b
DEBUG:   [            3412] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            3416] Playback 3 (B): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            3420] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Reserved 1 (C): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            3423] << 1c
TRAFFIC: [            3517] << 1c
DEBUG:   [            3611] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            3614] Reserved 1 (C): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            3618] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Reserved 2 (D): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            3622] << 1d
TRAFFIC: [            3716] << 1d
DEBUG:   [            3810] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            3813] Reserved 2 (D): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            3817] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Free use (E): POLL
TRAFFIC: [            3821] << 1e
TRAFFIC: [            3914] << 1e
DEBUG:   [            4008] >> POLL not sent
DEBUG:   [            4012] Free use (E): device status changed into 'not present'
DEBUG:   [            4016] << requesting active source
TRAFFIC: [            4019] << 1f:85
DEBUG:   [            5084] expected response not received (82: active source)
TRAFFIC: [            5091] << 1f:85
DEBUG:   [            6157] expected response not received (82: active source)
DEBUG:   [            6161] << requesting active source
TRAFFIC: [            6164] << 1f:85
DEBUG:   [            7229] expected response not received (82: active source)
TRAFFIC: [            7233] << 1f:85
DEBUG:   [            8297] expected response not received (82: active source)
DEBUG:   [            8343] unregistering all CEC clients
NOTICE:  [            8347] unregistering client: libCEC version = 2.2.0, client version = 2.2.0, firmware version = 1, logical address(es) = Recorder 1 (1) , physical address: 2.0.0.0, host: armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, features: 'P8 USB' 'P8 USB detect' 'RPi' 'EXYNOS', git revision: 9f000e4, compiled on: Thu Feb  5 19:25:20 UTC 2015 by root@raspberrypi on Linux 3.12.28+ (armv6l)
DEBUG:   [            8358] Recorder 1 (1): power status changed from 'on' to 'unknown'
DEBUG:   [            8362] Recorder 1 (1): vendor = Unknown (000000)
DEBUG:   [            8366] Recorder 1 (1): CEC version unknown
DEBUG:   [            8370] Recorder 1 (1): osd name set to 'Recorder 1'
DEBUG:   [            8374] Recorder 1 (1): device status changed into 'unknown'
DEBUG:   [            8378] unregistering all CEC clients
DEBUG:   [            9192] UnregisterLogicalAddress - releasing previous logical address
DEBUG:   [            9197] logical address changed to Broadcast (f)
```

--

And the following is what I get on `cec-client -l` :

```
Found Devices: 1

device: 1
com port: RPI
vendor id: 2708
product id: 1001
firmware version: 1
type: Raspberry Pi
```

It's also worth mentioning that I enable **Simplink** on my LG tv. However, its status is always *Check Connection*.

Any ideas !?
What is causing the problem?

***EDIT:***

I checked the connectivity of pin 13 on my HDMI cable (which belongs to CEC), and it was OK.

I still don't understand why I should change the cable!

Comment: Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: I checked the connectivity of pin 13 on my HDMI cable (which belongs to CEC), and it was OK.
I still don't understand why I should change the cable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a libCEC user, but a quick glance round their site revealed something on the [vendor support page](http://libcec.pulse-eight.com/vendor/support) regarding implementation of the "standby" feature for LG products; namely that it is "supported by all devices **except TVs**".

I'm not sure if that explains all your problems or not.  [LibCEC's front page](http://libcec.pulse-eight.com/) does have a "More" section at the bottom with some contact information, you could ask them directly about this.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks for your answer. I saw the vendor support page. It's sad that LG TVs don't support standby options over CEC. However, the problem now is that I cannot establish any CEC connection with my TV. Some people say that the problem is HDMI cable. I don't know!

Comment: I checked the connectivity of pin 13 on my HDMI cable (which belongs to CEC), and it was OK.
I still don't understand why I should change the cable!

Comment: I changed my HDMI cable to a Sony cable 3D version, and also changed the TV to samsung. Now it works ;)

Answer (score 4):

LG TVs do not support suspending over CEC.

Hardware workaround for LG TVs with WebOS not supporting CEC STANDBY https://github.com/ALFISYS/cec_lg_off

If you interested, take a look into my kodi screensaver - it does it over LAN. https://github.com/filimonic/Kodi.Screensaver.TurnOffLGTV